# Unable to deploy CXF services on JBOSS 8.2

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I am trying to deploy CXF (with MTOM Enabled) FileUpload service in JBOSS 8.2.

The service written is with the help of http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/04/cxf-file-upload-with-soap-mtom

I understand JBoss  8.2 has CXF Jars already shipped in its modules folder (I can locate them) hence i am not including them in the deployed war file.

My web.xml looks like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Despite this i am facing the below mentioned error:

```
18:04:16,389 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-16) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CloudReceiver.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CloudReceiver.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet from [Module "deployment.CloudReceiver.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:933)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:256)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet from [Module "deployment.CloudReceiver.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:651)
    ... 6 more
```

Does Jboss not load all the jars in 'modules' folder? If so how to get a particular jar loaded.

Any other pointer to solve this would also help.

Thanks in advance

Sudeep

Answer (score 1):

Try adding cxf dependency in your MANIFEST.MF file (inside META-INF folder of your war's root folder)

```
Dependencies:  org.apache.cxf.impl services
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am now using MTOM directly instead of having a CXF wrapper. So couldnt try this.

Comment: the dependency (for me at least) is packaged in: cxf-rt-transports-http